# How to add Android-WScratchView library to android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, import, build.gradle, importerror

I tried to add Android-WScratchView library(https://github.com/winsontan520/Android-WScratchView) to my project in android studio but I faced with this error:
Constant expression required Resource IDs cannot be used in a switch statement in Android library modules
Validates using resource IDs in a switch statement in Android library module. Resource IDs are non final in the library projects since SDK tools r14, means that the library code cannot treat these IDs as constants.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar situation。 And my solution is as follows:
original code：

```
MyOnClickListener mListener = new MyOnClickListener();
    mLayoutLeft.setOnClickListener(mListener);
    mLayoutRight.setOnClickListener(mListener);

    class MyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.layout_left: {
                    doSomthing1();
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.layout_right: {
                    doSomthing2();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

fixed code:

```
mLayoutLeft.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            doSomething1();
        }
    });
    mLayoutRight.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            doSomething2();
        }
    });
```

What I did is quite simple, hope I can help you;

Comment: [link](http://tools.android.com/recent/buildchangesinrevision14),maybe this post can help you also